# Thingsboard, access a server side attribute from the widget's javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, widget, thingsboard

As the title suggests I wanted to know how to access a server side attribute of the thingsboard Map widget.

My goal is to change the color of the polygon based on an attribute but I can't understand how to access this attribute from the javascript snippet in the appropriate area.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to select them from Alias panel. By the way you can see the attributes only if you choice a dashboard of type latest values. After you have selected the attribute you can use them from javascript panel:

```
self.onInit = function(e) {
    console.log("onInit()");
    console.log(self);
}
```

```
self.onDataUpdated = function() {
    console.log("start onDataUpdated()");
    console.log(self.ctx.defaultSubscription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same to mark different devices in a map depending on their alarm status. I added the attribute in the datasources tab in the widget configuration and was then able to use it with:

```
    data.attributename
```